# QuickConnet,PhoneGap framework native android app using java?

Tags: android

Hi i have heard lot about using frameworks for creating `native app`.i want to know that if i have and `android application` built using my `java code`.Can this framework convert it into app for any other mobile platform?or is it only for app's build in `HTML,CSS,javascript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about frameworks like [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/). The idea behind such frameworks is, you develop an app using web technologies like HTML5,CSS,Javascript. Since these web technologies are supposed to be cross-platform (to some extent), the porting becomes easy with minor tweaks.

Alternatively, if you develop an app say an android app using Android-SDK, then obviously it is gonna work only on android platform and you will have to rewrite the app for a different platform,say iOS.

Comment: aww so i can only write simple web based app's ..no database access and other things can be used?

Comment: You can still implement persistence(HTML5 supports webdb). Refer phonegap API for more details. Also you can add javascript interface for features that you don't find in phonegap.http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html